# repeat apply multiple times. Should I use a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

I have large matrices (zs) with five columns and 51695 lines such as:

```
str(zs1)
 num [1:51695, 1:5] 1.347 1.189 1.675 1.055 0.224 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "run 1" "run 2" "run 3" "run 4" ...
```

I would like to generate a vector containing median values for each 5 values in the zs column.

```
zs.stouffer1 = apply(zs1, MARGIN = 1, median)
```

How can I do this in a loop for i number of zs matrices?

This is my try:

```
for (i in 1:23) {
  zs.stouffer <- paste("zs.stouffer", i, sep = "")
  value <- apply(zs[i], MARGIN = 1, median)
  assign(zs.stouffer,value)
}
```

But i get:

> Error in apply(zs[i], MARGIN = 1, median) :    dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: Put the matrices in a list and then use `lapply` to run through the list. Something like `matList <- mget(ls(pattern="zs")); myMedianList <- lapply(matList, function(i) apply(i, MARGIN = 1, median))`.

Comment: Also have a look at `matrixStats` package. The function `rowMedians` could make things easier

Comment: In case you're wondering why the error, `zs[i]` is an indexing, it's not `zs1` if `i = 1`. If you want, you have to do the same `paste()` for it as you did in your function. `paste("zs", i, sep = "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `get(paste0("zs",i))` instead of `zs[i]`:

```
for (i in 1:23) {
  zs.stouffer <- paste("zs.stouffer", i, sep = "")
  value <- apply(get(paste0("zs",i)), MARGIN = 1, median)
  assign(zs.stouffer,value)
}
```

But as mentioned in comment above by @lmo it is better to combine matrices in list and use `lapply`.